# Talend Open Studio on Mac OS X - Failed to create JVM

Tags: macos, jvm, talend

I want to start the Talend Open Studio (ESB or DI) on my Mac Pro.

But I get an error: "Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine".

TOS Version is V5.6.0 and I have installed Java SDK 1.7.0_45 64-Bit.

I have also changed some values in TOS_ESB-macosx-cocoa.ini:

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
-vmargs
-Xms64m
-Xmx768m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/talend.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=../../../workspace
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

But I still get the same error.

I found that TOS use the wrong java version
    JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib

My JAVA_HOME is set to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Why have you reduced the max heap space from the default?

Comment: It might also be useful to state how much memory you have on your Mac Pro.

Comment: That are the default memory config by Talend Open Studio. I don't have reduced. I try different option, but this is the default by download the TOS. On my Mac Pro, i have 8 GB memory.

Comment: So what did you change? Checking the macosx-cocoa.ini on my Talend install has `-Xmx1024`.

Comment: So i try to change XXMaxPermSize to 1024m or to 512m, change Xmx, add -vm Param or add -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion to 1.7. But always the same result. Then i switch back to the default values (in my first post). I have download TOS_ESB-20141024_1545-V5.6.0.zip and there is -Xmx768m ...

Comment: I found that TOS use the wrong java version JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib

Answer (score 1):

It depend on that Problem https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65730.
I set the the link to libjvm.dylib in jre home and than TOS is starting.